# Selenium - Run user-agent mobile after logging in with desktop user-agent on Facebook

Tags: python, selenium, user-agent

So I am working on a auto bumper on Facebook where I bring up my post on sales market to let people see my post, Basically it is mostly for clothing market that I use so it is not for anything to harm something evil!

However, I am having problem when it comes to login with facebook.

Basically when you login with your mobile user-agent, There is two type of login by Facebook -

1. One is when they asking you for only email then you need to press Login then asking for you password
2. The second one is that it ask for email and password (Which I wish for) so basically it is the easiest way to login.

However to the problem is that whenever I try to run on desktop, the login is perfect, Works everytime.. However when I try to add a comment to BUMP, It can't find the correct ID since all the ID on on every comment has a unique facebook ID which there is none on Mobile version, Basically the wish I want ot make is that I want to login as a desktop and right after that use the mobile user-agent to do the comment, Is that something that is possible to do?

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('test-type')
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; HTC One M9 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36")
drivertest = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)


    driver.get("https://facebook.com/login")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(email)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_name("pass").send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("logging in..." + Fore.RESET)
    driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()
    time.sleep(3)


 i = 1
        for url in link:
            driver.get(url)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="composerInput"]""").send_keys(content)
            time.sleep(3)
            i += 1
            time.sleep(3)
```

Also please feel free to comment, Im usually fast to response if there is anything that I forgot to add.